# Control print to cell in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: asynchronous, jupyter-notebook, ipython, event-loop

Is there any way or magic word that can direct the code to print to specific location (output below the cells or console). I'm imagining something like below.

The reason I'm asking is, I have a sets of asynchronous co-routine started running  from jupypter notebook, which constantly print some output to show the result which I want them constantly showing in the console.  Meanwhile I want to using jupyter notebook to see some of object for debugging, and I only want to print some values in the cell output.

```
%print_here

print('hello')

%print_to_console

print('hello')
```